# Correct ontological relationship between "start" and "end"

Tags: time, owl, ontology

I've been cataloguing usage of some common ontology properties in OWL, RDFS, DCMI Terms, SKOS, etc. A question was brought up about how to relate start/end properties to one another (such as "start time" and "end time". [Schema.org](https://schema.org/startTime) and [OWL-Time](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/#time:hasBeginning) do not relate these to one another and Wikidata uses "complementary property" to relate [them](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P580).

My understanding is that "start time" and "end time" are not true complements to one another, as true complements would be something like "meats" and "non-meats" (for use of the property [owl:complementOf](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#complementOf-def), for instance).

After looking around at other ontologies, I can't seem to find one which relates start/end times to one another. Is there an ontology that does so? What is the relationship they have to one another ontologically?

Comment: I cannot imagine any relation between the two properties, other than an end date not being after a start date - but that relationship would be difficult to express ( start date value as min value for end date, maybe? Would be a different datatype range for each individual). Certainly nothing like a complement; maybe the intended meaning is that a start date suggests an end date would be meaningful?

Comment: I also don't see any other relation - something like "opposite" would only make sense if you consider directions on a timeline or similar.

Comment: I also don'T see how OWL axioms could help here as you can't make axioms based on values across different properties. The most natural constraint in my opinion would be to use an SWRL rule like: `start(?X, ?s), end(?X, ?e), lessThanOrEqual(?e, ?s) -> owl:Nothing(?X)` - this would make the whole ontology inconsistent once end would be before start (or equal, this indeed could be allowed, then use `lessThan` only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some properties of the cidoc-crm ontology have build-in properties related to start and end of envents.
It's simple and flat:  all the cases have a specific property.
These properties are:

- P173 starts before or with the end of
- P174 starts before the end of
- P175 starts before or with the start of
- P176 starts before the start of
- P182 ends before or with the start of
- P183 ends before the start of
- P184 ends before or with the end of
- P185 ends before the end of

example
[image: example cidoc crm]

You'll find doc about them here: https://cidoc-crm.org/html/cidoc_crm_v7.1.2.html#P173